# Adding foreign key to a column fails

Tags: mysql

I used the following two queries. The column is added to the table but the second query doesn't work.

```
 alter table rooms add column productid  int not null;  
 alter table rooms add foreign key(productid) references stock(productid) on delete cascade;
```

What am i missing?

Comment: "*Doesn't work*"  is not an acceptable error description.

Comment: Can you add the `stock` table description?

Comment: Name varchar(45) NO   
Price float NO   
Category varchar(45) NO  Unknown 
Dated datetime NO   
Sno int(11) NO UNI  auto_increment

Comment: There is no `productid` column in your `stock` table?

Comment: ProductId smallint NO PRI

Comment: @VijayaRagavan Have you tried my below solution

Comment: Ya that works vignesh. Why is it without inserting values don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an index on that field before adding a foreign key.

But when you create your foreign key, it won't work because of "NOT NULL". Actually, you have to remove "NOT NULL", populate your data and then write back "NOT NULL".

Also, rooms.productid and stock.productid must be same type.

Try this:

```
alter table rooms add column productid  int
alter table rooms add index (productid)
alter table rooms add foreign key (productid) references stock (productid) on delete cascade
```

Comment: alter table rooms add column productid  int not null, add foreign key(productid) references stock(productid) on delete cascade;    Is this syntax right pal?

Comment: Pal, can we use mysql workbench for plsql programming?

Comment: I don't use it so i don't know, but i guess it's mysql only, regarding on its name.

Comment: plsql is oracle's pal.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
alter table rooms add productid  int null;  
 alter table rooms add foreign key(productid) references stock(productid) on delete cascade
```

Comment: Dont use column keyword when using new column in table and you can not insert null column if there is data already in table. there is slightly modification.